# unicode url in cms pages, how?

Tags: magento-1.8, url, cms

How can I have UNICODE URL for CMS pages in magento ?

I have unicode url in products, catalogs and categories but need in cms pages too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are number of files responsible for allowing UTF-8 characters at the URL Key, These files include:

```
\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Cms\Page\Edit\Tab\Main.php
\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\Model\Resource\Page.php
\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Category.php
\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Url.php
\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Request\Http.php
```

Use this tutorial for details on how make Magento accept [Unicode URL Key for Products, Categories, CMS Pages](http://killerwhalesoft.com/blog/magento-unicode-url-key-products-categories-cms-pages/)

Answer (score 2):

By default Magento does not support using unicode characters as URL key. To overcome this you can use an extension such as [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/19389/)

Comment: I don't need use extensions like this! all the extensions only allow to use UNICODE for products and categories(that I have it now) , I want use UNICODE for cms pages

Comment: Do you even read, bra? "Allows Unicode UTF-8 NON-English /NON-Latin Characters to be used as URLKey of Categories, Products, **CMS Pages**".